# SpringData Cassandra Java Adapter - Using UDTs in Map Columns

Tags: user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

I am using the 1.5.1 version of the Cassandra adapter for Java, and I am attempting to insert a record to a table having a Map column that uses a UDT as the column value (key is just a varchar). I created the table using cqlsh and am able to insert to it in CQL just fine. When i try to use a CassandraTemplate...insert(), though, all I get is:

UserTypeResolver must not be null

My UDT class is defined as:

@UserDefinedType("iss_type")
public class IssueType {

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String issue_code;

@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String issue_name;

@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
private Date issue_start;

@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
private Date issue_end;
```

And my table is defined as
@Table
public class IssueMap {

```
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID map_id;

    @Column
    private Map<String, IssueType> issue_map;
```

In my config, i have:
    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        BasicCassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
        mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster().getObject(),"campaign_management"));
        return mappingContext;
    }

Is there something I am missing here? Or is it just not possible to define columns this way? I realize I could just use a query builder to create the CQL and do the insert, but I was hoping to be able to make full use of the Cassandra template features.

Comment: Looks as if there is another `BasicCassandraMappingContext` bean that is not configured with `UserTypeResolver`.

Comment: are you sure that "campaign_management" is your keyspace name?

Comment: @TBlank: I am also facing same error, did you get what was the reason?